# How to view entire array in MongoDB shell without truncation?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I am trying to find out the distinct values of a field using the `db.collections.distinct(<field>)`command.

The above command retrieves all the distinct values of the given field inside an array. But as I have 12k documents all the values are not getting displayed in my console.

This is the output I get; how do I view the entire result?

```
> db.dummy.distinct("dineRatingCount")
[
  null,      '6391573', '7780279', '6434564', '6761878', '3310772',
  '7347435', '2657046', '1054165', '6351703', '3400666', '8380233',
  '9400183', '5708289', '4303540', '5921412', '3596752', '6677940',
  '5641409', '8683847', '2874620', '2392159', '6405989', '6682474',
  '9453088', '9335486', '8688344', '8036721', '9090412', '6045969',
  '5640223', '6820181', '9748932', '7040773', '3683845', '4162813',
  '7538482', '2764420', '5630659', '6304861', '5628430', '8011166',
  '1912403', '8855139', '8861703', '4175488', '6180727', '4914295',
  '2904422', '1187556', '4707649', '7010787', '5239511', '5149672',
  '2180740', '9855302', '6133666', '3072308', '7600516', '8670256',
  '1390702', '3632377', '5251961', '4552278', '6606445', '6243124',
  '1812204', '2213617', '2564475', '1788878', '5261363', '6731404',
  '8514847', '9289278', '7091775', '5936085', '4796291', '2735993',
  '1188367', '8907823', '5307456', '6924707', '7127922', '9730023',
  '8811050', '1113740',
  ... 302 more items
]
```

I have searched the internet and documentation but I was not able to find an answer.

Comment: is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705517/how-to-print-out-more-than-20-items-documents-in-mongodbs-shell

Comment: @RenatoC.Francisco Nope sir, I am not sure whether the answer would work for distinct() method. More over the answer present there is for viewing an entire document.. not array values...

Comment: Would you be willing to update your question to have the output be plain text in a code block, rather than an image?  Generally, text-only images are [frowned upon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1108305), unless there's something the image is showing that a pasted version of that text would be missing.  If you don't want to make that change (e.g. you don't have the code handy any more), I can paste my example in from my duplicate question, since it shows the exact same phenomenon (https://stackoverflow.com/q/69399541/1108305).  Just give me the go-ahead, and I'll make the change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `mongosh` is a Node.js environment. There are several solutions, e.g. `JSON.stringify` the array or use [util.inspect](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinspectobject-options).

```
JSON.stringify(db.collections.distinct(<field>))

util.inspect(db.collections.distinct(<field>), { maxArrayLength: null })
```

Comment: I like that `util.inspect` appears to be the normal way things are printed in the shell (leaving out the `maxArrayLength` option gives the same truncated view).